# return CURSOR resultset from one stored procedure to another oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, cursor

I am facing issues while passing CURSOR resultset from one stored procedure to another in ORACLE. The Values retrieved shows null always.

```
Create or replace proc_1 (arranged_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
begin
---- here there is query that joins a couple of tables and I get the result. (not saving result set into any temporary table)
strquery :='SELECT DISTINCT A.COL_A, A.COL_B,B.COL_B FROM T_ALLOC A INNER JOIN T_MAIN B ON A.COL_A= B.COL_A';
OPEN arranged_cursor for strquery;
end
```

Next Procedure from where I am calling PROC_1

```
Create or replace PROC2()
as CC SYS_REFCURSOR;
var_A INTEGER;
var_B INTEGER;
var_C INTEGER;
begin
PROC_1(CC);
fetch CC INTO var_A,var_B,var_C;
EXIT WHEN cc%NOTFOUND;
-- here var_A, var_B and var_c are always null
END LOOP;
end;
```

Please help me .. What am I doing wrong? Should I insert the resultset from procedure 1 to temporary table? Only then will it work?
Please stuck here very badly.

Comment: Hi there pros, any help

Comment: No idea why you're using dynamic SQL in `proc_1`.  That seems to serve only to complicate matters.  If you are not getting errors and you're not getting the data you expect, I would guess that your query is wrong.  Since you don't provide a reproducible test case, though, it's nearly impossible to guess what the problem might be.